# Unix loop over output of cut

Tags: bash, loops, unix, grep

I have a bunch of `slurm` jobs that produce standard output and error files with this format:

```
<string>.<string>.<string>.<job_id>.ERR
```

where `job_id` is the job id assigned by `slurm`.

So to get these job ids I can:

```
cut -f 4 -d "." *.ERR
```

I'd like to pipe the output of this command to a loop that will run `sacct -j <job_id>` and `grep` which jobs have failed, using:

```
sacct -j <job_id> | grep "FAILED"
```

Can this be done in one command?

Answer (score 6):

You could use a Bash `read` loop, with process substitution:

```
while read -r job_id; do
  sacct -j "$job_id" | grep "FAILED"
done < <(cut -f4 -d. *.ERR)
```

You could also use `xargs`, which is more succint:

```
cut -f4 -d. *.ERR | xargs -n 1 sacct -j | grep "FAILED"
```